# Accessing variant image via id. Python

Tags: python, image, shopify

I'm trying to use Shopify's python API to get variant image url, I have received image_id and trying to do Image.find but I receive error, please help!

```
image = shopify.Image.find(variant.image_id)
image_url = image.scr
```

Comment: How are you obtaining the image ID?

Comment: for variant in product.variants:
variant.image_id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

image = shopify.Image.find(variant.image_id, product_id=product.id)

Answer (score 1):

If you already have the `Product` resource, then you have all the data you need without making an extra API call to Shopify. Simply take the `image_id` from the variant you want and loop through the images on `product.images` to see which one matches.

Example:

```
image_id = product.variants[0].image_id # Or however you pick the variant

image_src = None
for image in product.images:
    if image.id == image_id:
        image_src = image.src
        break
```

Or, to wrap it into a function:

```
def image_src_by_id(product, image_id):
    image_src = None
    for image in product.images:
        if image.id == image_id:
            image_src = image.src
            break
    return image_src
```

Comment: image = shopify.Image.find(variant.image_id, product_id=product.id) just one line

Comment: As noted, using `find()` makies another unnecessary API call to Shopify, and thus will be much slower (especially if you're doing this in a loop).